# Context is null in the global.asax file

Tags: asp.net

I have global.asax file, and I use this two functions to update cache value every 15 seconds by this code:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    Context.Cache.Insert("value","some value",null,DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(15),Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,CacheItemProirirt.Default,new CacheItemRemovedCallback(updating));
}

private void updating(string key,object value,CacheItemRemoveReason reason)
{
    Context.Cache.Insert("value","updated value",null,DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(15),Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,CacheItemProirirt.Default,new CacheItemRemovedCallback(updating));
}
```

but it give me an NullReferenceException, and the context is null, please why I can't use context at the "updating" function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Application_Start` doesn't have any context.

The first event that does is `Begin_Request`.

`Application_Start` occurs when the particular website gets fired up for the first time, or after been recycled.

---

To keep the cache item renewed I suggest you do that in the `Begin_Request`, where you check if it's there, and if not, initiate it again.

This way it's only use memory while the site is being hit, otherwise not.

Comment: thanks for answer, but it  give me null value of context at updating function not application_start

Comment: Of course it errors, the callback doesn't occur during a request, it occurs in the background and there is no context either.

Comment: @MiasSilentKiller Updated my answer with a suggestion